# Link ckeditor two text areas for Text Flowing from one text box to another

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, inline, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor.net

As I need to run ck-editoer inline text box boxes that contain a sequence of ck-editor text area. the word lets you flow text from one text box to another:

When the first text box is full, Word automatically moves to the next text box and fills it.

And apart of above: If you add or delete text in a text box, Word adjusts the text in the subsequent text boxes accordingly.

So can we achieve it using ck-editoer?

As I have tried the following

```
 $(document).on("keyup", "#iinlineTxt1", function (e) {
    var firstTextBox = document.getElementById('inlineTxt1');

    if ((firstTextBox.scrollHeight) > firstTextBox.offsetHeight && e.keyCode != 8) {

                     var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['inlineTxt2'];
                     editor.focus();
        }
}
```

But in the above case also I am getting the issue let say a user is typing and if he has not typed the entire word, it jumps to another instance

Comment: What have you tried yourself to achieve this, and what is causing you problems.

Comment: have updated the question, Thanks for reviewing it.

Comment: Do you use CKEditor 4 or CKEditor 5? The code indicates CKEditor 4, the tags CKEditor 5.

Comment: Ops! , Have updated the Tag.